# UnsupportedNodeException: Request for a node that is not part of the specified profile and components for this stream: viewpoint

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, x3d

I've been stuck on the same problem for some time and I don't know why I get the following Run-time error when I run my project.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.web3d.vrml.lang.UnsupportedNodeException: Request for a node that is not part of the specified profile and components for this stream: viewpoint
    at org.web3d.vrml.renderer.DefaultNodeFactory.createVRMLNode(DefaultNodeFactory.java:730)
    at org.web3d.vrml.renderer.ogl.OGLMainSceneBuilder.startNode(OGLMainSceneBuilder.java:147)
    at org.web3d.vrml.renderer.ogl.OGLVRMLSceneBuilder.startNode(OGLVRMLSceneBuilder.java:514)
    at org.web3d.x3d.jaxp.X3DSAVAdapter.startElement(X3DSAVAdapter.java:830)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1364)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at org.web3d.parser.GeneralisedReader.parse(GeneralisedReader.java:261)
    at org.xj3d.impl.core.loading.DefaultWorldLoader.loadNow(DefaultWorldLoader.java:156)
    at org.xj3d.impl.core.loading.DefaultWorldLoader.loadNow(DefaultWorldLoader.java:203)
    at org.web3d.vrml.scripting.browser.X3DCommonBrowser.createX3DFromURL(X3DCommonBrowser.java:264)
    at org.web3d.vrml.scripting.external.sai.SAIBrowser.createX3DFromURL(SAIBrowser.java:843)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.<init>(Xj3DTest.java:50)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.main(Xj3DTest.java:56)
```

My `Java` code for this is

```
package xj3dtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.Browser;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DComponent;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DScene;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Xj3DTest extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Setup browser parameters
        HashMap requestedParameters=new HashMap();
        requestedParameters.put("Antialiased",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("TextureQuality","medium");
        requestedParameters.put("PrimitiveQuality","medium");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_InterfaceType","SWING");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationReadOnly",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ShowConsole",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_OpenButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ReloadButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_StatusBarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_FPSShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ContentDirectory","CurrentDirectory");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_AntialiasingQuality","low");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_Culling_Mode", "frustum");

        System.setProperty("x3d.sai.factory.class", "org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl");
        X3DComponent x3dComponent = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(requestedParameters);

        Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add((javax.swing.JPanel)x3dComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[] {"test.x3d"});

        browser.replaceWorld(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xj3DTest frame = new Xj3DTest("Xj3D test");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The `X3D` files that I need to pass through it so it displays contain a `viewpoint` and `imageTexture url` tags which are tested to cause the problem. When I delete those tags from within the `X3D` files, it does work but doesn't have the desired output as it seemed to be zoomed in and have no texture the the `X3D` file.

The `Jars` that I'm using are `gluegen-rt, gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64, gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64, gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586, j3d-core-1.3.1, jhall, joal, joal-natives-linux-amd64, joal-natives-windows-amd64, joal-natives-linux-i586, joal-all, joal-all-natives-linux-amd64, joal-all-natives-windows-amd64, joal-all-natives-linux-i586, xj3d.browser_2.1.0-nps, xj3d.cadfilter_2.1.0_nps, xj3d.2.1-3rdparty-nps, xj3d.2.1-nps, xj3d-core, xj3d-runtime, xj3d-script-base`. The way that I've set the VM Options is by using `-Xmx450M -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\jar"` and I have added the library that contains all the `Jars` to the project.

**EDIT**
*It's still not working*

**EDIT#2**

The two tags that are causing the problem are

`<viewpoint centerOfRotation="7 1 0" position='10 0 40' orientation='0 0 0 1'></viewpoint>`

`<imageTexture url='"http://somewebsite.com/images/test.jpg"></imageTexture>`
Bare in mind that the above website isn't the website where the image is stored but it follows the same format.

**EDIT #3**

The code in the `X3D` file is now
`<viewpoint centerOfRotation="7 1 0" position='10 0 40' orientation='0 0 0 1'></viewpoint>`

`<imageTexture url="http://somewebsite.com/images/test.jpg"></imageTexture>`

And I'm still getting the viewpoint error and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Since it is a very specific issue, If I were you, I would specify clearly how to set up your environment? Where did you get the libraries? Which version do you use? ...

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I set up the environment by following the instructions provided by Xj3D. I created my own library called `Xj3D` which contains all the `Jars` that I need for it to run

Comment: Normally caused by bad jar files.

Comment: @I_am_Batman How would I detect it if it was a bad jar?

Comment: @I_am_Batman I've tried to redownload them and I'm still getting the error

Comment: @smitty could you share "test.x3d" file or explicitly copy those tags from within the X3D that you know cause the problem

Comment: @smitthy I notice you have single and double quotes for parameters, with url='" (single+double) is it a typo or your actual code?

Comment: @Preuk it's my actual code

Comment: @smitthy then your XML is invalid, you should remove the extra single quote on url attribute definition

Comment: @Preuk thanks, how would I get rid of the `viewpoint` bit of the error?

Comment: @smitthy have you tried checking your XML against X3D schema? http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.3.xsd ; you could also use consistent format for your attibutes (single vs. double quote), some parsers are not tolerant...

Answer (score 0):

For the first tag, the error was obviously a bogus single quote on `url` attribute.

For the second one, you could try using consistent quotes for all of your attributes, some parsers happen to fail on this.

Globally, you could start there:

- check well-formedness of your XML with tools like [this validator](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)
- check that your X3D is valid against the xsd declared in your XML header. There are a few references for validators [on this page](http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/X3dResources.html#AuthoringSupport), but the most efficient way is still using an XML authoring tool of your choice.